# Block fumacrom.com from appearing in posts

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, spam, short-links, blocklist

The domain "fumacrom.com" is an alias for "adf.ly", which [I just came across as a spam link on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70552121/7509065). Since we already have adf.ly on the blocklist, we should add fumacrom.com to it too.

Comment: you could visit Charcoal-HQ and bring it up there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq

Comment: @Vickel It's on their list. I think the request is to add it to the network-wide list that's maintained by SE, not by a third party.

Comment: @Mast Indeed it is.